# How can i request Http with authorization headers

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have issue with Guzzle POST request

here's my code

```php
$req = $client->request('POST', $endpoint, [
      'headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$this->api_credential
         ], $body);
```

its always response 401 
`"Please include your API key as an Authorization header"`

do i have to encode base64 the credential ?

and its using basic authorization

Comment: What are the specifications of the endpoint?

Comment: what credentials are you talking about? what does the API documentation say it wants?

Comment: The solution will be based on your API provider's specs. Can you link to a reference guide from this API provider?

Comment: im sry for the late answer
here's the docs
https://docs.xendit.co/postman/

Comment: added an answer for you, good luck with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API you are trying to authenticate with you will need to `base64_encode` the credentials for `Basic` authentication (`username:password`)[where `username` is your API Secret Key and `password` will be blank]:

For the Authorization header:

```
'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode($this->api_credential .':'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bearer instead of Basic authorization. Hope it will solve the issue

```
$req = $client->request('POST', $endpoint, [
      'headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->api_credential
         ], $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your server accept authorisation header. .htaccess code to accept authorisation header is given below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

You can check if the server accept authorisation code by using the following curl request

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://yourendpoint.com/apiFile.php'  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' .$api_credential
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
$returnData = json_decode($result, true);
```